# What is difference between selenium-server-standalone and selenium-server.

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can see two repository in Maven Central repo. Please clarify what is difference between both jars

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [Selenium documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp):

> You may, or may not, need the Selenium Server, depending on how you
>   intend to use Selenium-WebDriver. If your browser and tests will all
>   run on the same machine, and your tests only use the WebDriver API,
>   then you do not need to run the Selenium-Server; WebDriver will run
>   the browser directly.
>
> There are some reasons though to use the Selenium-Server with
>   Selenium-WebDriver.
>
> - You are using Selenium-Grid to distribute your tests over multiple
>     machines or virtual machines (VMs).
> - You want to connect to a remote
>     machine that has a particular browser version that is not on your
>     current machine.
> - You are not using the Java bindings (i.e. Python, C#,
>     or Ruby) and would like to use HtmlUnit Driver

The `selenium-server-standalone.jar` was used in older Selenium versions (with Selenium Server).

Newer versions of Selenium (WebDriver API) uses `selenium-java.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *Selenium Server jar* releases, `selenium-server-standalone jars` are no more pushed to the [Maven Artifact](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/).

Till *Selenium Release v2.53.0*, `selenium-server-standalone jars` were pushed to the [Maven Artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-standalone) separately as *Jenkins Releases*. But starting *Selenium Release v3.x* only the [selenium-server](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server) jars and the [selenium-java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) client jars are pushed to the [Maven Artifact](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/)

---

### Solution

1. If you running everything on the same machine, then using the  **selenium-java** client maven dependency should be just fine.
2. If you running something on a machine that's not your desktop, then using the  **selenium-server** maven dependency must be used. In this case you can also embed the Selenium server into your own project by adding the `selenium-server` dependency to your `pom.xml`.
3. If you intent to use the **`RemoteWebDriver implementation`**, then you need to download the **`selenium-server-standalone.jar`** from the [Selenium Downloads page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)