# Properly starting/stopping Selenium standalone server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the Selenium standalone server for a remote web driver. One thing I am trying to figure out is how to start/stop it effectively. On their documentation, it says

"the caller is expected to terminate each session properly, calling either `Selenium#stop()` or `WebDriver#quit`."

What I am trying to do is figure out how to programmatically close the server, but is that even necessary? In other words, would it be okay to have the server up and running at all times, but to just close the *session* after each use with something like `driver.quit()`? Therefore when I'm not using it the server would be up but there would be no sessions.

Answer (score 1):

While using [Selenium standalone server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559491/what-is-difference-between-selenium-server-standalone-and-selenium-server/46560899#46560899) as a Remote [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you need to invoke `quit()` method at the end to terminate each session properly.

As per best practices, you should invoke the `quit()` method within the `tearDown() {}`. Invoking `quit()` **DELETE**s the current browsing session through sending **"quit"** command with **{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}** and finally sends the *GET* request on **/shutdown** *EndPoint*. Here is an example below :

```
1503397488598   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> DELETE /session/8e457516-3335-4d3b-9140-53fb52aa8b74 
1503397488607   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   -> 37:[0,4,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
1503397488821   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /shutdown
```

So on invoking `quit()` method the `Web Browser` session and the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) instance gets killed completely.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)
- [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)

Answer (score 0):

you were right. Use seleniums `driver.quit()` as it properly closes all browser windows and **ends driver's session/process**. Especially the latter is what you want, because you most certainly run the script headless.

I have a selenium script running on as Raspberry Pi (hourly cron job) headless. That script calls `driver.quit()` at the end of each iteration. When i do a `-ps A` (to list al active processes under unix), no active selenium/python processes are shown anymore.

Hope that satisfies your question!